# removing &nbsp; before binding to label in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to remove all `&nbsp;` (which I store in database) before the data bound to the label.

I have tried:

```
Text='<%# Eval("nvQuestion").ToString().Replace("&nbsp;"," ") %>'
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: It should replace. Are you getting some error or something?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

it can help you

```
Text='<%#((string)Eval("nvQuestion")).Replace("&nbsp;", " ")  %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Eval("nvQuestion").ToString().Trim()
```

The `&nbsp;` is coming from a leading *space.* More specifically, if you're getting an `&nbsp;` you have *more than one* leading space.